# PHP : call abstract class functions without class name

Tags: php, oop, joomla

I have one abstract class like:

```
   <?php
    abstract class loader
    {
        public function using($path='')
        {
            return loader::import($path);
        }
        public static function import($path = '')
        {
            return 'a';

        }
    }
```

And after include it,i call using function with below command :
loader::using();

I need solution for call using() function without class name:
using();  instead of loader::using();

It solution  used in joomla "jimport".
How to do it (Jimport)?
Jimport is a function in abstract class ,but call this without classname::
Please Help.

Comment: Why do you need this? What's the point?

Comment: Just for learning.This is a big question for me,Joomla how to do it?

Comment: You only need to use Jimport if your class name is not autoloading.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a `using` function to the global namespace, that will act as a shortcut. By the way, I think `loader::using` should be a static function.

```
<?php
    abstract class loader
    {
        public static function using($path='')
        {
            return self::import($path);
        }
        public static function import($path = '')
        {
            return 'a';

        }
    }

    function using($path) {
        return loader::using($path);
    }
```

Comment: But in joomla jimport not static,I was inspired this from Joomla.

Comment: If you're running on php 5.3 of less, or have warning outputs set to off, PHP will allow you to use non-static methods as static, but it's a bad practice, nonetheless. BTW, I don't see the need for class abstraction in this particular case.

Comment: As far as I can see, in joomla 3 at least, JLoader::import is a static method, and it's called exactly as @amenadiel has outlined in his answer. I belive you might have missed that function jimport(); on the bottom of the file loader.php is infact outside the class JLoader, that is why this function is not static, and can be called without JLoader:: first. http://www.reference.joomlademo.de/libraries/loader.php.source.txt